# QGIS settings to generate a valid GPX file for Strava

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, gps, gpx, strava

I downloaded a GPX file from an activity in strava that had some errant points that caused the distance and elevation to be off that I want to try to correct. I imported the file in to QGIS and saved it to a geopackage to edit the points.

[image: import of original]

I edited the track and the points from the GPX file. After removing some bad points and vertices in the file, I exported the layer back to a GPX and tried to upload the file to Strava.

[image: settings]

I've used various settings on the export screen for GPX in QGIS but none of them are accepted by Strava.

[image: rejection]

When I upload the points, it says the file is empty. When I upload the line, it says the data is missing the time values.

If I import the various GPX files that I have created with QGIS, they import with `waypoints` instead of `track_points`.

[image: wrong gpx format]

Does anyone have some tips on how to correct a GPX track with QGIS and export it successfully for Strava?

### Update

Here is a sample of the downloaded strava gpx.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx creator="StravaGPX" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
 <metadata>
  <time>2022-12-09T16:30:37Z</time>
 </metadata>
 <trk>
  <name>Strava</name>
  <type>3</type>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="" lon="">
    <ele>1</ele>
    <time>YYYY-MM-DDTHHMM:SSZ</time>
   </trkpt>
  </trkseg>
 </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: Does it work if you reupload the file that you downloaded? 
So does it accept the download-format?

Comment: @Nunkuat yes it does accept the downloaded format.

Comment: Okay, than please open both files (downloaded and edited) in an editor and post the first ~ 30 rows.

Comment: @Nunkuat the edited file is in a geopackage. I want to figure out how to export it from QGIS. I'll update the question with the downloaded format.